# How can I thicken Acid Stain myself?

Tags: concrete, staining

I have been doing a lot of decorative concrete around my house, and I have yet to find a masking tape or caulking or anything that can hold the acid stain where I want it.  I finally found something that I think will work, [it's a gel](http://www.directcolors.com/decogel/) that makes the stain thicker and keeps it in place.  This way you can just paint it where you want it.  The problem is that it is not sold in the colors that I want.  So, does anyone know what I could add to an acid stain to make it thicker like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick [Google](http://www.google.com/) search turns up [Modello Gel-lo](http://www.modelloconcrete.com/techniqueDetails.asp?idno=44996)

> Modello Gel-lo is a thickening agent for  liquid coloring mediums such
>   as acid and water-based stains for concrete. The addition of Modello
>   Gel-lo allows for more controlled color application and helps to
>   reduce "wicking" of the stains under the edges of the Modello
>   patterns.

And [Stain Mule™](http://www.surfacegeltek.com/products06.html).

> Stain Mule will thicken both acid stains and water based colorants.
>   When color placement control is necessary, the Mule is your product.

Comment: I'd go with the first one, that way if somebody asks "What's that stuff you're using". you could break into [song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellow_Yellow) "They call it Modello Gel-lo".

Comment: You know, I had found those before and that is how I knew that it exists.  Maybe I should have thought of that before offering a bounty.  But the funny thing is that you cannot buy either of those products.  That is why I was looking for something that I could actually get.  Oh well.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually, just on a lark I called the contact number for the Stain Mule, and the lady let me order it direct.  Thanks a ton for making me look at that again @Tester101